# How to define an empty Tuple?

Tags: scala

I have the following function definition:

```
  private def extractUrl: String => (String, String)
  = url =>
    url
      .split("/")
      .toList
      .filter(_.startsWith("localhost"))
      .flatMap(e => e.split(":").toList)
      .foldLeft[(String, String)](("", "")) { (acc, x) =>
        acc match {
          case ("", "") => (x, "")
          case (a, "") => (a, x)
          case z => z

        }

      }
```

the question is, is there another way to define an empty `Tuple` instead of `("", "")`?

Comment: No that I know, the empty tuple is the **Unit** `()`. But they would have different types. However, it seems you have a **List** fo two elements or more elements and you want the first two, is that right?

Comment: the function works as expected. I just curious, how to create an empty tuple

Comment: Your tuple is not empty, it contains two empty string instances.  @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez is right.

Comment: You could consider `String => Option[(String, String)]` instead

Comment: Glad that it works for you, but your code does all sorts of things that make no sense. You might consider posting it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Empty tuple

`("", "")` is a tuple of empty strings with type `(String, String)`.
Empty is unclear in that context, could be `(None, None)` or even `(null, null)` (bad)

You seem to use `""` to represents a value that is not present. Try using `None` and Some[String], both sub types of `Option[String]`, to indicate that a value is not present.

## Analysis and comments

- Potentially, your method seems not to do what is intended. (execute code below)
- Think about using already present functions / methods / libraries for manipulating URLs (also see example below)
- Think about using Option

```
object Fun {

  import java.net.URL

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val url1 = "http://localhost:4000/a/b/c?x=1&y=2#asdf"
    val url2 = "http://example.com:4000/a/localhostb/c?x=1&y=2#asdf"
    val urls = List(url1, url2)

    // your approach
    println("Your approach")
    urls.map( urlString => extractUrl(urlString ))
      .foreach(println)

    println("New approach")
    urls.map(x => extractUrl2(x))
      .filter( x => x.host.startsWith("localhost") )
      .foreach(println)
  }

  case class HostPort(host: String, port: Option[String])

  def extractUrl2: String => HostPort = urlString => {
    val url = new URL(urlString)
    HostPort(url.getHost,
     url.getPort match {
       case -1 => None
       case i => Some(i.toString)
    })
  }


  def extractUrl: String => (String, String) = url =>
    url
      .split("/")
      .toList
      .filter(_.startsWith("localhost"))
      .flatMap(e => e.split(":").toList)
      .foldLeft[(String, String)](("", "")) { (acc, x) =>
        acc match {
          case ("", "") => (x, "")
          case (a, "") => (a, x)
          case z => z

        }
      }
}
```

yields

```
Your approach
(localhost,4000)
(localhostb,)
New approach
HostPort(localhost,Some(4000))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to define an empty Tuple.

I tried to use `(->)` but that resolves to a `Tuple2.type` and not a `Tuple2`.

If the values of your Tuple are optional, use the type system to express that:
`(Option[String], Option[String])`

Better yet, you could define a case class for your data structure:
`case class HostAndPort(host: Option[String], port: Option[String])`

Comment: "I don't think it is possible to define an empty Tuple." – It doesn't make sense to talk about "**an** empty Tuple". **The** empty Tuple is unique, there can only ever be one. It is commonly called "the unit value" instead of "the empty tuple", though. It is usually written using Tuple syntax, including in Scala: `()` is the empty Tuple value, and `scala.Unit` is the empty Tuple type.

Answer (score 0):

This would provide default values for each type within the tuple:

```
let my_tuple: (String, usize) = Default::default();
```