# Initialize an empty tuple scala

Tags: string, scala, initialization, tuples, is-empty

I want to create a mutable tuple in scala `(String, Set[String])`.
And before I want to initialize it to an empty value first before adding to it

the set can not be initialized to empty set.  The same for String.
I'm getting an error saying `class java.lang.String is not a value` 
Is there a simple way to do that ? and What am I doing wrong

Comment: A tuple is not mutable and it can't not be empty. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty `Set` can be defined like so

```
Set.empty[String]   // because assert(Set.empty[String].isEmpty)
```

Empty `String` can be defined like so

```
""                  // because assert("".isEmpty)
```

[Empty tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58018329/5205022) is not something Scala models as `TupleN`, I think. Instead it uses `Unit` type for it. Perhaps you are after something like so

```
val ta: (String, Set[String]) = ("", Set.empty)
val tb: (Option[String], Option[Set[String]]) = (None, None)
val tc: Option[(String, Set[String])] = None
```

The error message

```
class java.lang.String is not a value
```

means you are using a type where value is expected, for example, consider the difference between

```
Set[String]    // ok
Set(String)    // error
```

Comment: You may also `var ta: (String, Set[String]) = _` - which is the same as `var ta: (String, Set[String]) = null`